# MonoTouch UIViewController with dynamic type

Tags: c#, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, dynamictype

I have a UIViewController in MonoTouch, defined together with a .xib as an iPad View Controller.

If i change the UIViewController to use a dynamic type like this:

```
public partial class CustomCount : UIViewController<tUnit> where tUnit : struct
    {

        private tUnit someVariable;
     ... (rest of class goes here) ...
```

Then monoTouch no longer seems to generate corresponding .h and .m files in it's xCode project for this view controller.

Because of this, i can no longer access any of the UI outlets (as they are defined in the .m file)

If i remove the `tTUnit` dynamic type, everything works fine.

The `where tUnit : struct` portion makes no difference to MonoTouch.

Is there any known solution to this, or should i just create sepearate versions of my class for every type i am expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is being a `struct` required?  You could use an interface otherwise.

Can you do this instead:

```
public partial class CustomCount : UIViewController
{
    //Use a static method here
    public static CustomCount Create(ISomeInterface yourVariable) { return new Customcount() { someVariable = yourVariable }; }

    //Private Constructor
    private CustomCount() { }

    private ISomeInterface someVariable;
}
```

You could event just make `someVariable` a public property or something.

Comment: In this case, being a struct is preferred, but not a requirement per sé, this is a decent option though. +1

Comment: If you are worried about performance, using an interface isn't going to hurt you very much at all.  You can also make structs inherit interfaces: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx